# How can I simplify the code using just the tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse

so I have the data frama below, and I'm trying to creat a new Data frame which show me the name of the department which have the highest and the lowest employee turnover. The code that I write is correct, but is too big, so I am wondering how can I simpkly it. Thanks

**My data:**

```
df = data.frame(
          department = c("admin", "engineering", "finance", "IT", "logistics", "marketing", "operations", "retail", "sales", "support", "admin", "engineering", "finance", "IT", "logistics", "marketing", "admin", "retail", "admin", "engineering"),
          promoted = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
          review = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1, 0.9, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.55, 0.4, 0.33, 0.11, 0.1, 0.11, 0.1),
          projects = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1),
          salary = c("low", "medium", "high", "low", "medium", "low", "medium", "low", "low", "low", "medium", "high", "low", "medium", "low", "medium", "low", "low", "low", "medium"),
          tenure =  c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1),
          satisfaction = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1, 0.9, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.55, 0.4, 0.33, 0.11, 0.1, 0.11, 0.1),
          bonus = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
          left = c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no"))
```

**My Code:**

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df%>%
   count(department)

colnames(df1) <- c('department','Total')


df2<- df%>%
  filter(left == "yes")%>%
  count(department)

colnames(df2) <- c('department','Yes')



df2$Yes<-as.numeric(df2$Yes)
df1$Total<-as.numeric(df1$Total)


df3 <- inner_join(df1, df2)
head(df3, 10)
  

df3Max <-df3%>%
  mutate( turnover = Yes/Total ) %>%
  arrange(desc(turnover))
df3Max <- head(df3Max, 1)


df3Min <-df3%>%
  mutate( turnover = Yes/Total ) %>%
  arrange(turnover)
df3Min <- head(df3Min, 1)
```

Comment: This question is likely more appropriate for the forum [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) which specifically optimizes working code.

Comment: Try running your sample code.  It doesn't work.  You have mising commas and unequal numbers of entries in the columns.  help us to help you by checking your code before you post.

Comment: Replace the `colnames` lines with `rename`.  Then you can add it to the pipe.  In fact, `count` takes a `name = ...` variable to let you name it directly.  Also, the `as.numeric` seem unnecessary.  Also, for the max/min part, you probably want to `pull(turnover)` to get the value, not a tibble containing the value.